# AMD Radeon Pro 555X and Myst Selentic Age Mazerunner

Tags: gpu

Cyan advised that some AMD GPUs have a driver issue that causes the Mazerunner to be unplayable (interior of the vessel very dark). Is there any driver update or other workaround for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMD make separate Boot Camp drivers for Mac - https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/apple-boot-camp
but the macOS drivers are in macOS itself & not available separately.

On Mac, to update the drivers, you update the OS.